# How to fix this error that occured using pinput package?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, package

Last number is different

[image]

I don't know this fix

[image]

Comment: please specify your error with code. not the images.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.